# Clone monitor in Windows via software (not hardware or driver)

Tags: .net, directx, multiple-monitors

I have an application where I would like to have 3 monitors, where two have independent video streams, and the third is a switch-able clone of the other two. Essentially, "Extended Desktop" on monitors 1 and 2, then a "conditional clone" on monitor 3.

My issue, is while AMD and NVidia support this with Eyefinity and Mosaic, respectively, my application needs to run on Intel Integrated Graphics, which has no driver or hardware-level support for what I describe.

So, is there some functionality built into DirectX or other Windows drawing library, that can allow me to capture a screen, then display that screen on another monitor? So far, trying to directly copy the back-buffer has proven prohibitively slow (seconds worth of delay, and extremely slow refresh rate).

Comment: I can't help but notice you have the .net tag. I can't imagine any way to do this in a managed system and be performant

Comment: If it is possible to do this using an un-managed setup, then I'm sure that can be arranged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows 7/8 there is the [desktop duplication API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which has a [`DuplicateOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

MSDN describes the desktop duplication API as follows:

> Windows 8 disables standard Windows 2000 Display Driver Model (XDDM)
>   mirror drivers and offers the desktop duplication API instead. The
>   desktop duplication API provides remote access to a desktop image for
>   collaboration scenarios. Apps can use the desktop duplication API to
>   access frame-by-frame updates to the desktop. Because apps receive
>   updates to the desktop image in a DXGI surface, the apps can use the
>   full power of the GPU to process the image updates.

There is a sample implementation [on MSDN here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Desktop-Duplication-Sample-da4c696a).